# when login attempt is exceed more than 3 than user cant to login using spring security Rest API?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I am using spring boot with security in java. i have a Override this method `UserDetails lodUserByUsername(String email)`.

I want when user enter wrong email and password then provide response "Invalid Username and password"

if their email exists and they will enter the wrong password then that particular user of attempt is increase by one and store into a database table of column attempts.

if that user has a exceed limit more than 3 than I want response "Your Username is Blocked"

if that user first two or one try to enter the wrong password then the only attempt is increased and show response "Your attempt is"+MIN_ATTEMPTS.

if the user has enter first two or one try enter wrong password then after they can enter the correct username and password then that particular user of attempts set to 0.

```
 private static final int MAX_ATTEMPTS = 3;
    int MIN_ATTEMPTS = 0;

 @SneakyThrows
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) {
        Members members = membersDao.findByEmail(email);
        Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
        if (members == null) {

            throw new Exception("Invalid username and password");
        } else {
            MIN_ATTEMPTS = members.getAttempts();
            MIN_ATTEMPTS++;
            members.setAttempts(MIN_ATTEMPTS);
            membersDao.save(members);

        }
        if (members.getAttempts() <= MAX_ATTEMPTS) {
            APIResponseBuilder.build(true   , commonMessages.loginSuccess);
            return new User(members.getEmail(), members.getPassword(), authorities);
        } else {
            throw new Exception("You have exceed max +" + MAX_ATTEMPTS + "+limit of login");
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you please explain in simple what is your requirement ?

Comment: What is the problem statement?

Comment: i had already explain above with requirement

Comment: username and password both is wrong entered than it can  work properly. but when i enter correct username and incorrect password than i want to add attempt in database otherwise not. if username and password is correct then i don't want to update attempt into database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added above code into my authentication controller and problem is solved

1.controller

```
private static final int MAX_ATTEMPTS = 3;

@PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<?> login(@RequestBody LoginMembers loginMembers) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
        Members members = membersDao.findByEmail(loginMembers.getEmail());
        PasswordEncoder passencoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

        if (members == null) {
            //Create Error Message for User
            throw new RuntimeException("Invalid Username and Password");
        }
        if (members.getAttempts() >= MAX_ATTEMPTS) {
            //Create Error Message for User
            throw new RuntimeException("Login Attempt exceeds "+MAX_ATTEMPTS);
        }

        if (passencoder.matches(loginMembers.getPassword(), members.getPassword())) {
            final Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                            loginMembers.getEmail(),
                            loginMembers.getPassword()
                    )
            );

            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            final String token = jwtTokenUtil.generateToken(authentication);
            logger.info("You are log in successfully with token");
            return ResponseEntity.ok(new AuthTokenRequest(token));
        } else {
            int attempts = members.getAttempts();
            members.setAttempts(++attempts);
            membersDao.save(members);
            //Create Error Message for User
            throw new RuntimeException("Login attempts "+attempts);
        }
    }
```

2. Method

```
@Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) {
        Members members = membersDao.findByEmail(email);
        Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
        try {
            Role role = members.getRoles();
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getRole()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            APIResponseBuilder.build(false, e.getMessage(), commonMessages.exception);
        }
        return new User(members.getEmail(), members.getPassword(), authorities);
    }
```